# Can anybody suggest me how to implement jquery sparklines in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, jquery, javascript-controller

I have Loaded jquery sparklines static resource downloaded from https://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-news still i cant use functions in it to implement sparklines in LWC

this is my html code

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="testing">
    <div class="jqtest">  </div>
    <div class="jqs">  </div>
</lightning-card>
```

this is js code

```
    import {LightningElement, track,api } from 'lwc';
import jq from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/Jq';
import JQSP from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/JQSP';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class TestingJquery extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback(){
        Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, jq),
         loadScript(this,JQSP)
        ])
        .then(() =>{$(this.template.querySelector('div.jqtest')).text('This is testin text');
        $(this.template.querySelector('div.jqs')).sparkline([1,1,1,4],{type:line});
        console.log('sparkline Executed');
    
    } )
        .catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
                    message: 'cant load message',
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate DOM objects, you need to set `lwc:dom="manual"` on the element to control. This is in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/js_third_party_library):

> Using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM isn’t recommended because the Lightning Web Components engine does it more efficiently. However, there are some third-party JavaScript libraries that take over the DOM.
>
> If a call to appendChild() manipulates the DOM, styling isn’t applied to the appended element.
>
> When using these libraries in a Lightning web component, add lwc:dom="manual" to any HTML element that you want to manipulate with JavaScript. When the engine sees the directive, it preserves encapsulation.
>
> Add the lwc:dom="manual" directive to an empty native HTML element. The owner of the component calls appendChild() on that element to manually insert the DOM.

Comment: Its still not working  I have done what you suggested

Comment: @TejaParsaS. are you getting an errors?

Comment: No just not loading the sparkline,I am not getting any errors. With same static resource I have executed aura comp it has loaded the sparkline properly but not loading in this lwc or not working i think